# My notebook goes offline automatically after some time

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-printer

I have about 3 computers and 1 windows 2003 server in office and 1 network printer (HP LJ 2840).

- My network printer is installed on the server.
- I an sharing this printer on all clients with windows XP.
- All other computers are fine only 1 HP laptop.

When I start that HP laptop the printer works fine but after some time, printer goes offline and I can't print until I restart the laptop.

When that laptop goes to offline mode, I can work on that laptop, I can use shared network drives, I can ping server but it shows offline mode icon in Task bar status area.  If i use `\\servername` I can see the server's shared items and if i go to printers I can't see any printer...

I try my best to solve this issue, but I can't.

Thanks

Comment: Given it's such a small network have you considered just setting each machine up to print directly rather than via the server?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting the computer try restarting the Print Spooler service.  Check the event log on the laptop to see if an errors are being logged.